# How to make an existing directory within a git repository a git submodule

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

### I'm very confused about git-submodules.

Basically my problem is that I can't make git understand that `~/main-project/submodule` is a submodule.

---

**I have good experience with git submodules:**
in my [dotfiles repository](https://github.com/Doron-Behar/dotfiles) I created the .gitmodules file in `~/dotfiles-repo` and I added there paths and urls. Since then, If I make changes to the files within the submodules and run `git status`, I'd get something like like: `.vim/bundle/auto-complete (new commits) # in red`

I created the `.gitmodules` file in `~/main-project` but:

- If I make changes to `~/main-project/submodule` and even push the changes, I don't get a similar response like `<submodule> (new commits) # in red` when running `git status` in `~/main-project`. **I just get the changes that were made in those directories**
- When I hit the folders' links at `github` for these directories it's not directing me to the repositories themselves but I stay in the same repository.

  1. Maybe I'm missing the whole point. What are the main features of submodules?
  2. Why does git understands the submodules in [the dotfiles repo](https://github.com/Doron-Behar/dotfiles/tree/master/.vim/bundle) but not [in my other repo](https://github.com/Doron-Behar/RFID-entry-permissions-sys)?
  3. Is it because I have already told git to add the files inside `~/main-project/submodule` to the index?

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593620/how-to-make-part-of-an-existing-git-repository-a-submodule) which led me to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920165/howto-extract-a-git-subdirectory-and-make-a-submodule-out-of-it/1307969#1307969) But I'm not sure I need `git-subtree`. I don't want to do things that might do changes hard to be revert.

> Edit: [This suggested duplicate-solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413493/create-a-submodule-repository-from-a-folder-and-keep-its-git-commit-history) didn't work either, I recieved an error that `Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do not have locally`. It seems that [@GabLeRoux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1092815/gableroux) practically told me to push `<repo-A>` to the url of `<repo-B>`.

Comment: To your main outer repository a Git submodule is just another file.  So you won't see changes inside the submodule appearing in `git status` on the outside.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a submodule repository from a folder and keep its git commit history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413493/create-a-submodule-repository-from-a-folder-and-keep-its-git-commit-history)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44699112/1122851

Answer (score 56, accepted):

#### Use `git submodule absorbgitdirs`

This is what the [docs](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.41.0/Documentation/git-submodule.txt#L253) state this command does:

> If a git directory of a submodule is inside the submodule,
> move the git directory of the submodule into its superprojects
> `$GIT_DIR/modules` path and then connect the git directory and
> its working directory by setting the `core.worktree` and adding
> a .git file pointing to the git directory embedded in the
> superprojects git directory.

So instead of starting all over as suggested in the previous answers by @DomQ and myself, one can just add run the following:

1. Without removing from the index the submodule, Add the submodule's url to `.gitmodules` and to `.git/config` with
   `git submodule add <url> <path>`
2. (**Optional but recommended step**) Move the submodule's `$GIT_DIR` directory (`.git` in regular repositories) to `.git/modules/<path>` with:
   `git submodule absorbgitdirs <path>`

#### Original answer - pre v2.12.0

`git submodule absorbgitdirs` was introduced only in [v2.12.0-rc0](https://github.com/git/git/releases/tag/v2.12.0-rc0) (see [commit](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6f858614003a3da794385cefdbddf00b85f7501)).

The Solution is quite simple. It was extracted from [here](http://blog.davidecoppola.com/2015/02/how-to-create-git-submodule-from-repository-subdirectory/).

1. `git rm submodule-dir`
   This will delete all the files that git was tracking after in `submodule-dir`
2. `rm -rf submoduledir`
   This will delete all the other files that might have been left in `submodule-dir` because git ignored them.
3. Now, we have to commit in order to remove the files from the index:
   `git commit`
   After the commit, we cleaned the files that git followed and didn't followed in `submodul-dir`.
   Now it's time to do:
4. `git submodule add <remote-path-to-submodule>`
   This will re-add the submodule but as a true submodule.
5. At this point it might be a good idea to check `.gitmodules` and see if the submodules have been added successfully. In my case I already had an `.gitmodules` file so I had to modify it.

Comment: I'd say, `rm -rf submoduledir` feels dangerous... I would do a `mv submoduledir submoduledir.backup` until I can see that the other commands worked. (Yes, I'm a bit paranoid.)

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot! As it has been a while since v2.12 now, I suggest moving the edit to the top of the answer.

Comment: rm -rf is a Linux command, nowhere in this thread it was implied that we are all using Linux, the answer should also contain the Windows CMD line equivalent, or at least clarify that it only works on Linux

Comment: conserning the new method, I still needed to do a `git rm -r <path>` first before being able to run `git submodule add`

Comment: I am confused why this answer is (needs to) be this complex? I did `git submodule add $MYURL submoduledir` and then it said "Adding existing repo" ... is that not enough? Maybe the question did not ask what I think it did ...?

Comment: @lucidbrot the answer (the updated as of currently) gives explanations as to what is being done by git under the hood. The `absorbgitdirs` command is not mandatory, but it is recommended. Indeed it can be stated that it's not mandatory. Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 30):

None of these solutions seemed to work for me so I figured my own:

1. Make sure a new git repo already exist that will hold the content
   of the new submodule, for example, we'll be using "**git@github.com:/newemptyrepo**"
2. Navigate to the directory you're modulizing:

```
cd myproject/submodule-dir
```

3. Remove the to-be submodule from the parent's index:

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

4. Init a new git repo inside the to-be submodule:

```
git init
```

5. Set up the origin for the to-be submodule and make your first commit:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:/newemptyrepo
git add . && git commit && git push --set-upstream origin master
```

6. Now you must navigate to the parent repo's top-level path:

```
cd .. && cd `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
```

7. Finally, add the submodule as you would normally:

```
git submodule add git@github.com:/newemptyrepo ./myproject/submodule-dir
```

8. Now commit & push the changes the above command makes and you're all set up!

Answer (score 6):

**There is basically no better way than pretending to start over**:

1. ensure that everything is committed everywhere
2. move your sub-repository out of the way
3. `git submodule add` from the sub-repository's remote
4. `cd mysubmodule`
5. `git fetch ../wherever/you/stashed/the/sub-repository/in/step-1`
6. `git merge FETCH_HEAD`

To explain why this is so, it seems to me than a deeper understanding of what submodules *are* is needed, than what one can glean from the [`git-submodule(1)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) manual page (or even the [relevant chapter from the Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)). I found some more in-depth explanations on [this blog post](https://matthew-brett.github.io/curious-git/git_submodules.html), but since that post is a bit lengthy I am taking the liberty summarize them here.

At a low level, a git submodule consists of the following elements,

- A [commit object](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) at the top of the submodule tree,
- (In recent versions of Git) A subdirectory in `.git/modules` to host the Git objects for the submodule,
- An entry in the `.gitmodules` configuration file.

The commit object is contained (or more precisely, referenced by SHA1) in the parent tree object. This is unusual, as things [usually](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) happen the other way round, but this explains why you see a directory appear in the main repository's `git status` after you have performed a commit in the submodule. You can also make [some experiments](https://matthew-brett.github.io/curious-git/git_submodules.html#storing-the-current-commit-of-myproject) with `git ls-tree` to observe this commit object in more detail.

The subdirectory in `.git/modules` stands in for a `.git` subdirectory in the submodule; and in fact, there is a `.git` *file* in the submodule that points to the former using a `gitdir:` line. This is the default behavior [since version 1.7.8 of Git](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.8.txt). Not sure why everything wouldn't Just Work if you just kept on having a separate `.git` directory, except as noted in the release notes you would probably run into trouble when switching between a branch that has the submodule and another that doesn't.

The `.gitmodules` file provides the URL that `git submodule update --remote` and friends should pull from; which obviously is distinct from the main repository's set of remotes. Note also that `.gitmodules` is copied in part into `.git/config` by the `git submodule sync` command and other commands that invoke it behind the scenes.

While it is fairly easy to do the necessary changes by hand for `.gitmodules` + `.git/config`, and also for `.git/modules` + `mysubmodule/.git` (and in fact, there is even `git submodule absorbgitdirs` for the latter), **there isn't really a porcelain to create only the in-tree commit object**. Hence the proposed solution by moving + redoing changes presented above.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions in order:

1. The [purpose](https://github.com/blog/2104-working-with-submodules) of submodules according to GitHub. Feature wise, it has been designed to be conceptualized a child repository (which can almost be treated like any other file), that is version controlled by a parent repository, where **the parent tracks the current commit ID of the submodule (child repository) rather than it's content**.
2. It's most likely because you've already added the files to the index of the repository. In which case, the solution is to `git rm --cached submodule-name/`. Then create an intermediate commit, followed by the adding of the folder **as a repository**: `git add submodule-name` (notice that there is **no trailing slash** after submodule-name in the case of submodules).
3. Yes :)

---

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/920165/2110869) you mentioned may correct the history of your commits as well:

1. **Advantages**:

That folder will be treated as a submodule in all of your commit history, not just all future commits. This avoids any complications if you checkout to a previous version where it was treated like a folder. This is a complication because when you return to the tip of your branch, you may have to enter your submodule also and checkout to the latest commit to restore all the files (which may be deleted from your working directory). This could be avoided by doing some kind of a recursive checkout to your latest commit.

2. **Disadvantages**:

If the commit history is modified, all other contributors would also have to re-clone the project since they will get merge conflicts or worse; reintroduce the problem commits back into the project.