# How to separate one file or folder with all history from one git repo to another?

Tags: git

Let me explain. For some time I developed some code. Now I want to separate a part and make it open-source. My main problem is to **save all commit history, which concerns that files**.

Comment: I doubt you can. Is it necessary to preserve history? Couldn't you make a new git repo, add the files you want, and label it "Initial Commit"?

Comment: That is not interesting

Comment: Also https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

Comment: Why some "bright mind" found making -1 is good idea?

Comment: -1 because the question is poorly worded and is a duplicate as I currently understand it. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I suspect you're asking is how to make a subdirectory (or just a set of files) into its own repository. If that is the case then you're asking a question that has been answered many times before:

- [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-move-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository)
- [How to make a part of a Git repository  a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593620/how-to-make-part-of-an-existing-git-repository-a-submodule)
- [Create a submodule repository from a folder and keep its git commit history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413493/create-a-submodule-repository-from-a-folder-and-keep-its-git-commit-history)
- [Rewrite history git filter-branch create / split into submodules / subprojects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425260/rewrite-history-git-filter-branch-create-split-into-submodules-subprojects)

and is well documented and googlable:

- [GitHub - Splitting subfolder out into a new repository](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/)

which goes against the advice on the ["How to ask" help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and makes this a candidate for being closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use git blame and save commit history to a file, like:

```
git blame <full_file_path> > blame_file.txt
```