# Reduce Git repository size

Tags: git, git-gc, git-clean, git-maintenance

I tried looking for a good tutorial on reducing repository size, but I found none. How do I reduce my repository size? It's about 10 MB, but [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku) only allows 50 MB and I'm nowhere near finished developing my application.

I added the usual suspects (log, vendor, doc, etc.) to the *[.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)* file already. Although I only added *.gitignore* recently.

What can I do?

Comment: I just did and it brought it down to 2.2 mb...thanks a lot! Although that didn't seem to reduce the repo size on Heroku..hmm

Comment: Push it using --force. It will overwrite the contents even if there was no change (no new commits, etc.)

Comment: @MarcinGil - Below, VonC states you need access to the server to clean the remote server (if I am parsing it correctly).

Comment: Just a comment to help other readers if they don't know what to add to the `.gitignore`, there is a nice service at gitignore.io that will help you set up a good `.gitignore` based on your dev environment.

Comment: Related (2009): *[Make Git consume less disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398919/make-git-consume-less-disk-space)*

Answer (score 475, accepted):

Update Feb. 2021, eleven years later: the new [`git maintenance` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64077241/6309) ([man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance)) should supersede `git gc`, and [can be scheduled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66298072/6309).

---

Original: [`git gc --aggressive`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) is one way to force the prune process to take place (to be sure: `git gc --aggressive --prune=now`). You have [other commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685319/git-pull-error-unable-to-create-temporary-sha1-filename/685422#685422) to clean the repo too. Don't forget though, sometimes `git gc` alone can [increase the size of the repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904860/how-to-remove-unreferenced-blobs-from-my-git-repo)!

It can be also used after a `filter-branch`, to mark some directories to be removed from the history (with a further gain of space); see  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository). But that means nobody is pulling from your public repo. [`filter-branch` can keep backup refs in `.git/refs/original`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709433/how-can-i-remove-the-unwanted-objects-from-my-repo-after-filter-branch-subdirec), so that directory can be cleaned too.

Finally, as mentioned [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size/2116892#comment43412037_2116892) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27489761/6309); cleaning the reflog can help:

```
git reflog expire --all --expire=now
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

An even more complete, and possibly dangerous, solution is [to remove unused objects from a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14729486/6309)

---

Note that [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) now (Git 2.24+, Q4 2019) replaces the [obsolete `git filter-branch` or BFG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309): it is a python-based tool, to [be installed](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/INSTALL.md) first.

[Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6937857/joe) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74592110/6309):

```bash
# Find the largest files in .git:
git rev-list --objects --all | grep -f <(git verify-pack -v  .git/objects/pack/*.idx| sort -k 3 -n | cut -f 1 -d " " | tail -10)

# Strat filtering these large files:
git filter-repo --path-glob '../../src/../..' --invert-paths --force
#or
git filter-repo --path-glob '*.zip' --invert-paths --force
#or
git filter-repo --path-glob '*.a' --invert-paths --force

git remote add origin git@github.com:.../...git
git push --all --force
git push --tags --force
```

Comment: In another scenario, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029969/why-is-my-git-repository-so-big

Comment: Note to self: don't forget remote branches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255802/delete-remove-binary-file-from-git-repository-is-still-large

Comment: Note to self: don't forget remote tags

Comment: In addition to remote references, the reflog is another thing that may cause references you are trying to remove to be kept.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/27489761/1072626

Comment: @vossad01 good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC I started `git gc --aggressive` but at the middle of the process it was interrupted because space at HDD was over and now my git repository has grown in size - and now I can not add more space - how can I fix this?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Note sure: ask a new question with the exact version of git and the OS used, to see if I or other git-questions contributors can suggest a fix.

Comment: Do we do a `git push` after this to push the changes to the server? I'm guessing not since it results in *`Everything up-to-date`*. Is there a way to clean the server directly?

Comment: @jww I confirm this is purely a local operation. It has no bearing on the size of the remote repo. You would need a direct access to the server of that remote repo to do the same.

Comment: I reversed the order above and clearing the reflog didn't help much when done after the garbage collection and pruning, which reduced my repo from 10 to 5 MB. Perhaps it should be done in the order specified. ;-)

Comment: I ran the original gc bits on my repo. My `.git` folder dropped from 1.7GB to 235MB. Great tip @VonC

Answer (score 128):

Here's what I did:

```
git gc
git gc --aggressive
git prune
```

That seemed to have done the trick. I started with around 10.5 MB and now it's little more than 980 KB.

You can run all three commands with prune till now using:

```
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

Documentation:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc

Comment: `prune` is always run by `gc` (with 2 weeks ago default).

Comment: U can run all 3 with prune till now using `git gc --aggressive --prune=now`

Comment: But, when I delete the repo then clone it again, the size is still large. How do you handle that?

Comment: if you delete your local repository and clone again you inherit the remote's .git folder. To keep the size reduction changes you likely have to at least push them yourself first. If you don't control the remote you're out of luck, but you could always make your own fork

Comment: after run the three commands, local repo became smaller, but run git status will show no update at all ,so it's no way to git commit & git push changes to remote repo... How to shrink remote repo?

Answer (score 31):

In my case, I pushed several big (more than 100 MB) files and then proceeded to remove them. But they were still in the history of my repository, so I had to remove them from it as well.

This did the trick:

```
bfg -b 100M  # To remove all blobs from history, whose size is superior to 100MB
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

Then, you need to push force on your branch:

```bash
git push origin <your_branch_name> --force
```

**Note**: [bfg](https://github.com/rtyley/bfg-repo-cleaner) is a tool that can be installed on Linux and macOS using [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) (executable `brew`):

```
brew install bfg
```

Comment: that is such a clean solution. 'git gc' and 'git prune' didn't help me from other answers.

Answer (score 1):

This should not affect everyone, but one of the semi-hidden reasons of the repository size being large could be Git submodules.

You might have added one or more submodules, but stopped using it at some time, and some files remained in `.git/modules` directory. To give redundant submodule files away, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule).

However, just like the main repository, the other way is to navigate to the submodule directory in `.git/modules`, and do, for example, `git gc --aggressive --prune`.

These should have a good impact on the repository size, but as long as you use Git submodules, e.g. especially with large libraries, your repository size should not change drastically.