# Trimming huge git repository size

Tags: git

I'm not that well versed in using `git`, but have been using Xcode and a local repository on my machine.

All seemed well, until today when I was trying to free up some space on my HDD.
I noticed that in my repository's `.git` directory there were a couple of large files (6.3 and 1.4 GB).

[image: Screenshot]

I have no idea what these files are for, and a Google search has revealed little about them.

Because I have a Macbook Air, storage space is at a premium.
I would like to find a way to compress or remove these large files, but I don't want to corrupt `git`'s version history.

Comment: FYI, a detailed thread that relates to large files in git http://metalinguist.wordpress.com/2007/12/06/the-woes-of-git-gc-aggressive-and-how-git-deltas-work/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce git repository size](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2116778/456814).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pro Git book has an excellent section on what to do when you've accidentally committed something huge into your repository:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery

Answer (score 6):

The screenshot shows two small index files and two huge packs. So I believe you have commited a few huge files in Git.

To find top 10 largest blobs, you can use the following command:

```
git verify-pack -v .git/objects/pack/<pack>.idx | sort -k 3 -n | tail -10
```

It should produce: SHA-1 blob size ...
Then you can look at this object using its SHA-1:

```
git show <SHA-1>
```

or you can learn its name:

```
git rev-list --objects --all | grep <SHA-1>
```

Answer (score 4):

Pack files are bundled history files that git uses.

If you want to clean up some space, do the following:

- `git branch` to list branches, and `git branch -d <old branch>` to delete old branches (do this first)
- `git gc` will clean and compact the repo
- `git prune` will remove extra files (like the `reflog`, which keeps track of all commits, even deleted ones)
- `git gc --prune=now` will `gc` and `prune` in one command

After doing this, I'd be interested to see how much space you save.  If your repo's history is really 7 GB, you'd probably be better off in moving it to an external HDD.