# "Destroy" Git repostiory from TFS database

Tags: git, tfs

I am trying to find the equivalent action of [`tf destroy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/vsts/tfvc/destroy-command-team-foundation-version-control)for a Git repository. That is to say, permanently delete the Git repository and recover the space in the database. Running TFS 2017 U3.

We have a number of Git repositories which where either added in error or are now obsolete and can be discarded. Merely ["deleting"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/vsts/git/delete-existing-repo) the repository does not appear to recover the space in the database. I am aware TFS cleanup runs on either a 5 or 7 day cycle to recover the space.

It appears TFS internally keeps track of the deleted repositories in a table - dbo.tbl_GitDeletedRepository, which also suggests they can be recovered (tho no option to do so).

Note: I am aware you cannot delete if only single repo is left.

In the alternative, is there a recommended approach to blow away the entire contents of the repository, compress the repository (`gc`?), push that to TFS and thus recover the space in the database?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?  I'm encountering the exact same issue, waited the 7 days that should have pruned it, but still no pruning.  I even have a completely deleted dataspace that hasn't been cleaned up.  It does look like it eventually gets pruned (I have two that have been.)  But I have some almost 2 weeks old and still hanging around.

Answer (score 0):

> There are many different types of files stored in TFS collection
>   databases, including Team Foundation Version Control files, Git files,
>   work item attachments, test case attachments, build outputs, etc. Not
>   all of them support cleanup. Also, note that file contents are not
>   generally cleaned up immediately upon deletion, but rather by a
>   background job that runs on a periodic basis (typically once per day).

For Git, you can try running below commands, then delete the repository. (Delete the entire Team Project if the projects are no longer needed)

```
git reflog expire --all --expire=now
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

Refer to this thread for details: [Reduce git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size)

You can also reference below articles to clean up the GIT repository:

- [GIT repository cleanup](https://vlukashevych.wordpress.com/2015/08/16/git-repository-cleanup-after-migration-from-tfs/)
- [Permanently remove files and folders from Git repo](https://dalibornasevic.com/posts/2-permanently-remove-files-and-folders-from-git-repo)
- [Completely removing all traces of files and history from Git
  repositories](https://blog.sdbarker.com/post/completely-removing-all-traces-of-files-and-history-from-git-repositories/)

Comment: I do not believe the advice applies. It's not about deleting contents from the repo, rather deleting the repo itself from TFS. From the UI, Version Control under Settings, choose a repo, right-click, Delete. Net result is it now ends up as an entry in DB [dbo].[tbl_GitDeletedRepository]. Entry also remains in  [dbo].[tbl_Repository] with [State] = 4. That suggests: 1) it's not really gone (as tf destroy does for tfvc objects), 2) it is recoverable, though no documentation on how.