# GIT - Reduce Size of Repo After Deleting stuff

Tags: git

I removed tons of images from my GIT repository and yet my project size still the same. I only have one Branch.

**How do I cleanup the size** of the git repo but making sure I keep the commit history there?

My GIT is remote.

Comment: Are those images still part of your git history?

Comment: What do you mean by removed? Did you run filter-branch? Otherwise it's still in the history.

Comment: i removed and pushed to the remote the removal of the files.

Comment: `git rm` is not removing the files from the history, so your repository/remote size will not decrease.

Comment: @user9729328 Be Nice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size)