# Is there a way to block my local repository from downloading history of commits?

Tags: git, github

I have git repository with size 38GB and rising.

Is there a way to have local "thin" repository which will contain only current state of remote repository without any history?

I tried `git clone --depth=1` but this only downloads repository with last change and not forcing repository to have always minimal possible size.

Comment: Just for curiosity, why your repository size is 38GB do you use .gitignore ?

Comment: @aydinugur it's very old project, with very large number of text files, there's no binaries in it. Beside this, programmers tend to do like 3-4 commits per every 10 min :P so history swells very fast.

Comment: Try `git gc`. The repository may have too many loose objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size)

Comment: You might want to increase the frequency of automatic `git gc` of loose objects. The default value (not documented anywhere) for `gc.auto` is 6700. Don't set it super-tiny right away—auto-packing of loose objects too soon will get you more packs but each one will be less efficient than a larger pack, and as soon as you have 50 packs you'll trigger a repack, which is slow. It will take some experimentation to find the right value to make Git behave best.

Answer (score 0):

Archive the current repo at a major release, say 1.0 -> 2.0. Create a new repo fresh with just the project files, and mark the old one as read only. This way you still have the history in the archive, but start with a fresh small repo.

This may not work well if you have to support multiple versions (clients still on previous versions, which patches need to be rolled into the current version).