# Project is not pushed on Github

Tags: github

I get fatal error frequently while pushing it on Github and gets hang for hours with no result. Is it due to my project's file size?
I get following errors:

```
1. 'unable to rewind rpc post data - try increasing http.postBuffer'
2. 'RPC failed; curl 56 SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 10054' and
3. 'fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedlyB | 7.00 KiB/s'
```

Any possible solution? Any suggestions highly appreciated

Comment: Are you using https to push your data ? Have you tried with ssh ?

Comment: @chmike I have tried ssh and not https

Comment: Total file size is 896 MB approx 900 MB, so is it due to size?

Comment: The problem could be on github side since it suggest to increase http.postBuffer while you are using ssh. Is your project using CI ? Are you uploading big data ? Binary ?

Comment: No... Its simple React Weather Project

Comment: 900MB is huge. That's most likely the cause.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203434/discussion-between-pranav-and-chmike).

Comment: Perhaps [Reduce git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2116778/1115360) would help. Note that git may not be good with binaries, such as images like jpegs.