# How to create clone a git-repo to local LAN

Tags: git, repo

Sometimes, one may need to execute the following commands to clone a repo to local.
The repo is around 100GB. So is there a way/how to setup to 'clone' the repo in the remote server 'examplecode.org' to a local server so that it didn't need to fetch the codebase remotely?

Originally, the commands to execute are:

```
$repo init -u git://examplecode.org/platform/manifest.git -b release -m ${MyTag} --repo-url=git://examplecode.org/tools/repo.git --repo-branch=my-branch-stable
$repo sync -f -j${CPUS}
```

Let's 192.168.1.100 be the server in local network, ideally, after the setup, the commands would be like:

```
$repo init -u git://192.168.1.100/platform/manifest.git -b release -m ${MyTag} --repo-url=git://192.168.1.100/tools/repo.git --repo-branch=my-branch-stable
$repo sync -f -j${CPUS}
```

`repo` means [git-repo](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo)

Many thanks

Comment: How do you imagine that the repository is stored locally without downloading it?

Comment: And what are those commands? For `init`, did you mean `git init`? And what is `sync` - there is no Git command with that name.

Comment: Hi @mkrieger, 1. ideally, it will download the code base once to a local server, then others can clone a working one from the local server rather than from the remote one, "examplecode.org"  2. `repo` mean [git-repo](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo)

Comment: I don't know that tool, but of course it is possible to do what you just described with Git. Did you try it? What exactly was the problem?

Comment: Similar to  'git --bare', to clone a local replicate of a remote repository to share to others. However, it is 'repo' command.

Comment: Yes. So did you try to run these commands you've shown in the question? What happened then?

Comment: The keypoint is how to setup the local replicate.

Answer (score 0):

Your repo is 100 GB? If that's not a typo, you might consider ways to reduce that size.

A good way to start might be by looking for logical ways to split the existing code (and probably a lot of non-code...) across multiple repositories. Is the code base sufficiently modular, such that you could move different modules into their own repository?

And speaking of non-code, are there a lot of large binary files being kept in the repo? Maybe those could be taken out of the version control system and moved elsewhere,like a LAN drive or a sharepoint site. A lot of the benefits of version control are lost with binary files and they just end up taking a ton of space.

Last, you might want to [run `git-gc` to clean/optimize the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size). This is especially true if you are self-hosting a centralized "master" server (rather than using Github or something similar), since that may not be happening automatically at regular intervals.

**Edit**:
 I realize this doesn't directly answer the stated question. But it seems OP may have some other areas to explore that would make the sought after solution less urgent.

**Edit 2**:
Based on the comments, it sounds like there is some confusion about what `git` does versus what `repo` (the Android wrapper for `git`) gives you on top of git. First, and most importantly, *you can freely switch between `repo` and `git` commands*. Using one does not bar you from using the other. The `repo` script is just a wrapper that simplifies some operations that are common when developing for Android, but which are cumbersome to do manually with `git`. Outside of those operations, most of the repository manipulation will probably be done using the standard `git` commands.

Regarding the original question, what you are describing is the `git clone` command:

> **NAME**
>         *git-clone* - Clone a repository into a new directory
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> git clone [--template=<template_directory>]
>           [-l] [-s] [--no-hardlinks] [-q] [-n] [--bare] [--mirror]
>           [-o <name>] [-b <name>] [-u <upload-pack>] [--reference <repository>]
>           [--dissociate] [--separate-git-dir <git dir>]
>           [--depth <depth>] [--[no-]single-branch] [--no-tags]
>           [--recurse-submodules[=<pathspec>]] [--[no-]shallow-submodules]
>           [--jobs <n>] [--] <repository> [<directory>]
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>   Clones a repository into a newly created directory, creates remote-tracking branches for each branch in the cloned repository (visible using `git branch -r`), and creates and
>          checks out an initial branch that is forked from the cloned repository's currently active branch.
>
> After the clone, a plain `git fetch` without arguments will update all the remote-tracking branches, and a `git pull` without arguments will in addition merge the remote master branch into the current master branch [...]

Since you specifically mentioned wanting to have the code base on the local network, you would first clone the repository and then pull all branches:

```
git clone [remote URL]
git pull --all
```

Once that is done, you can use any `repo` and regular `git` commands to manage your local copy of the repository.

Comment: After `repo sync`, the codebase is >=100GB is possible, for instance, Android's codebase. However, the size is not a issue. One may still consider setup a local copy to share in a office / network is not stable and so on.

Comment: If you're really just trying to make a local copy of a remote repository, why can't you just use `git clone [remote url]`??? Using `repo` doesn't preclude you from using the typical `git` workflows, and it sounds like what you're describing is really just `git clone`. After you clone the repository you should still be able to work with it using `repo` commands as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found 2 ways to do it:

1. Using `repo`'s `--mirror` option to create a local mirror, then use `--reference` to checkout by referencing the mirror
2. Using `grokmirror`, pls ref https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/grokmirror/grokmirror.git/tree/README.rst